# C language basics

Tags: c

I type in the following code in the linux terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a;
    a=1;
    printf("%d\n",a++);
}
```

now the output is shown as 1 and not 2.Why is it so that i'am incrementing
the value of a by using ++ operator but still the value stored in a is not incremented.Please help.

Comment: Please google the difference between pre-increment and post-increment. This should be covered in almost all C books and tutorials.

Comment: The "Linux terminal" will not execute C code (should be true for any shell).

Comment: Google down? It was really easier to post a question here instead searching yourself??

Comment: The result of `a++` is the value of `a` *before* the increment; use `++a` to get the result you're expecting.  Note that in both cases, the update to `a` is a *side effect* of evaluating the expression.

Comment: @Olaf It is a basic question, yet it clearly poses the problem, output and expected output.  Better than many first time posts.

Comment: @chux: I agree about the quality, but imo it is clearly below standard, much like a simple typo. It shows no research and an answer can be found easier than posting a question here. If such questions would be accepted, wouldn't that make SO kind of tutorial/teaching site?

Comment: @Olaf  Consider http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293946/2410359

Comment: @chux: I take the freedom to disagree. Answering every tutorial-like question will flood SO with such, making the more important quite difficult to find. Note that there is already a problem to find dups. Things might be different, if there was higher rep required to vote up, but - admittedly - this is a critical subject.

Comment: @Olaf Although `a++` appears trivial, notice both answers incorrectly imply the sequence of operations (return value, and then incrementing of `a`) as if that was specified.  It should be "The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented"  (sequence not specified).  That has interesting optimizing repercussions when `a=INT_MAX` and `int` overflow is UB.  I did not post an answer as that would confuse OP, but even for advanced users, the subtleties of even `a++` are not trivial.

Comment: @chux: Might be a language gap, but I do not read this implication from the answers. They do not state when the increment occurs. Your comment, however, raises a general problem with answers to such questions: where to stop? Sure, you now can add sequence points, then re-ordering, etc. This is actually another reason to recommend reading a book if such a question is asked.

Comment: @Olaf Hmmmm, What is this thing you call ["book"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book)? Is not that some ancient form of communication like a [rune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stele)? You can have the last word.

Answer (score 5):

a++ is post increment. So it first assigns the value of a where it is used and then it increments.

execute the following two examples. You should get a clear idea between pre and post increments:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a, c;
    a = 1;
    c = a++; // assigns the value 1 to c and increments the value of a
    printf("a: %d and c: %d\n",a,c);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, c;
    a = 1;
    c = ++a; // increments the value of a and then assigns it to c
    printf("a: %d and c: %d\n",a,c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in C, suffix operator `++` increment the variable's value after you use it. so your statement is equivalent to

```
printf("%d\n",a);
a += 1;
```

You intended behavior could be achieved by using prefix `++`:

```
printf("%d\n", ++a);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
a += 1;
printf("%d\n", a);
```